# ListView positioning after filtering

Tags: java, android, listview

I have searched but I do not understand the answers, I have a ListView, the filter works but when it filtered result is clicked on, the initial position is what it brings up, opening an unwanted activity. Here is my code

```
public class IndexPageActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {
ListView listView;
EditText editTextB;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.indexpage);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.pageList);
    editTextB = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchB);
    String[] pages = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.page_data);
    // Row layout defined by Android: android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1
    adapter1 = (new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, pages));
    listView.setAdapter(adapter1);
    adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    editTextB.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
            IndexPageActivity.this.adapter1.getFilter().filter(cs);
            adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int index, long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (index == 0) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, WebViewActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("keyHTML", "file:///android_asset/page1.html");
        startActivity(i);
    } else if (index == 1) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, WebViewActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("keyHTML", "file:///android_asset/page2.html");
        startActivity(i);
```

How do I make the filter work with the right string/item when the filter is in the works?

Thanks

Comment: can you be a little more specific? when you click the 2nd item of your list, `index` is not `1` ?

Comment: In normal mode, the list view works, when filtered, and the item filtered is in the first position it returns the HTML page in the first position of the first Initial listview, when actually the filtered item is in position 3 maybe,

Comment: because your listview has a/ no idea it is being filtered b/ anyway it does not know about the position of the current items in the topology of the original list. You need to put your urls in the items you are displaying, rather than hard coding it like that.

Comment: @njzk2 I dont get your explanation, how do I put the URLs in the items? The items are in a XML file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Filtered ListView onItemClick returns Item at original position](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14562556/filtered-listview-onitemclick-returns-item-at-original-position)

Comment: Thanks @njzk2 I saw that too before posting the question, how would you use the answer given with my code above. Please explain if you could. Thanks

Comment: More simply, you should probably test the item rather than hardcoding the id.