# Filtered ListView onItemClick returns Item at original position for online Activities

Tags: android, listview, listview-filter

Hi I am trying to make a apps that contains some `list item` with auto `suggestion` from a `website`. but when i `Click` one of the Item it return only first item related value. But i want only `related value` from them.

This is my `Main Activity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView vl;
    Button b;

    // List view
    private ListView lv;

    // Listview Adapter
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    // Search EditText
    EditText inputSearch;


    // ArrayList for Listview
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> news_title;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        vl = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myList);
        b= (Button) findViewById(R.id.addNewbutton);
       inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSerach);

        fetchingData();

        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddingNews.class));
            }
        });


    }



    void fetchingData(){

        String myURL = "http://192.168.56.1/android/api/gettingnews.php";

        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(myURL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                final String[] news_title = new String[response.length()];
                final String[] news_detail = new String[response.length()];
                final String[] news_time = new String[response.length()];

                for (int i =0; i < response.length(); i++){

                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) response.get(i);

                        news_title[i] = jsonObject.getString("title");
                        news_detail[i] = jsonObject.getString("news");
                        news_time[i] = jsonObject.getString("time");



                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
             //  vl.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.mylistview, R.id.textViewforlist, news_title));


                // Adding items to listview
                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.mylistview, R.id.textViewforlist, news_title);
                vl.setAdapter(adapter);

                inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                        // When user changed the Text
                        MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                                  int arg3) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    }
                });




                vl.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Details.class);

                        intent.putExtra("MyTitle", news_title[position]);
                        intent.putExtra("MyNews", news_detail[position]);
                        intent.putExtra("MyTime", news_time[position]);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d("Volley Log", error);
            }
        });

        com.example.forkan.tuntuninews.AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonArrayRequest);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Data Loaded Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();




    }


}
```

and this is `My Details: activites;`

```
public class Details extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView title, time, details;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);

        title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytitle);
        time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytime);
        details = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mydetail);

        String _title = getIntent().getStringExtra("MyTitle");
        String _news = getIntent().getStringExtra("MyNews");
        String _time = getIntent().getStringExtra("MyTime");

        title.setText(_title);
        time.setText(_time+"\n\n");
        details.setText(_news);


    }
}
```

How Can i Fix it Please Help me..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtered ListView onItemClick returns Item at original position](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14562556/filtered-listview-onitemclick-returns-item-at-original-position)

Comment: But where i can use that adapter

Comment: @ForkanAkon you'd need to declare your own adapter (which should extend `BaseAdapter`).

Comment: Sufian if u give a link or example it would be very helpfull to me